# Low Stock Report: How to Add a Manufacturer/Brand column?

Tags: inventory, reports

In the low stock report I need to add the manufacturer/brand as a column for each ID or product name, so that I'm able to prepare stock requests per manufacturer.

Any help to accomplish this is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have override the core Class for Increase stock.

**Step 1:** Override the grid Class in local folder.

**Step 2:** In Prepare Column add below Code.

```
 $this->addColumn('brand',
        array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Pending'),
            'type' => 'string',
            'filter' => false,
            'sortable' => false,
            'renderer' => 'Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_brand'
        ));
```

**Step 3:** create File `app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Renderer/brand.php`.

**Step 4:** Copy and paste below code.

```
<?php

class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_brand extends  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
   public function render(Varien_Object $row){

    $data=Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($row['entity_id']);
    $brandName=$data->getData('brand');
    return number_format($brandName,0);
   }
}
```

**Step 5:** Refresh cache and check in your Grid.

Comment: good answser. +1 for it.

Comment: Thanks Keyul. I've followed your steps, however, low stock report shows up now as a blank page. Note that manufacturer is an "attribute" that I created and added to an "attribute set" to be assigned individually to each product. For Step 2 I've copy-pasted your code in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Product/Lowstock/grid.php (85). For Step 3 I created the file in "Lowstock_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_brand", should I create this inside "app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/..." instead?

Comment: Tried to write brand.php like this: <<?php

class Local_Lowstock_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_brand extends  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
   public function render(Varien_Object $row){

    $data=Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($row['entity_id']);
    $manufacturer=$data->getData('brand');
    return number_format($manufacturer,0);
   }
}

Comment: what is actual problem then